# Error while encrypting the password in mysql

Tags: mysql

I created table like this

```
create table my(username varchar(23),
                rolnumber varchar(12),
                pword varchar(50));
```

Trying to insert values like this

```
insert into my 
            values ('sandeep','10r81a0229',aes_encrypt('ori12','sand12'));
```

getting error:

> 1366 incorrect string value

Answer (score 0):

`AES_ENCRYPT()` returns binary data which can't be stored in `VARCHAR` field. You should use appropriate field type, like blob, instead.

From [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html):

> if you want to store binary values such as results from an encryption or compression function that might contain arbitrary byte values, use a BLOB column rather than a CHAR or VARCHAR column

Comment: I changed the datatype from varchar to blob.but who see password is there any other query because                                                                                               select * from my where username='sandeep';                                                                                is not showing the password atleast encrypted also not showing

Comment: If you do `SELECT AES_DECRYPT(pword,'sand12') FROM my WHERE username='sandeep'` you should see the password decrypted. But instead of encrypting passwords you should definitely look into hashing them, properly.

Comment: yes i am using password as BLOB.                    atleast I want to see encrypted password

Comment: `SELECT * FROM my WHERE username='sandeep'` will retrieve the encrypted password. As it is binary information what gets shown may depend on what client you use to execute the query, terminal settings and various other things. As an example MySQL cli running on Debian gives me "}<BE>4z֯<B1>^Q<AB>g"<8A>Ng<82><A4>".

Comment: after inserting values like this insert into my 
            values ('sandeep','10r81a0229',aes_encrypt('ori12','sand12'));          it is showing executed sucessfully. now i want to see all data in table. I wrote select * from my. it is showing all field's data correctly expect the pword filed.in pword fiels it is showing blob

Comment: I am using mysql version 5.6.22

Comment: It's depending on your client whether you see just 'blob' or the actual data. See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28c82/3) for example. First two result sets are base64 coded and last one isn't.